# How to log out both server and client same time in OAuth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0

When authorization success, after when log out of client or server, how to information to exchange between client and server to remove token accsess? To that account log out same time between client and server, thanks every body!

Comment: OAuth2 doesn't have anything to say about logging in or out, so the question doesn't really make sense. It's not part of the standard.

Comment: but must have a method when we log out of server then the same time we auto log out client as facebook.